# MUI DataGrid MT - how to do show a div under selected row with a custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a MUI DataGrid MT version, I'm not allowed to buy the PRO version that has the master detail out of the box, so I need to create my own implementation.

What I have is this:

```
const toggleRowExpansion = (rowId : any) => {
    setExpandedRow(expandedRow === rowId ? null : rowId);

    const rowElement = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${rowId}']`);
    if (!rowElement) {
      // Row not found, possibly handle this case
      return;
    }

    let detailElement = rowElement.nextSibling as HTMLElement;

    
    if (!detailElement || !detailElement.classList.contains('detail-row')) {
      detailElement = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement;
      detailElement.classList.add('detail-row');
      detailElement.innerHTML = `<div>Your custom content for row ${rowId}</div>`; 
      
      rowElement.parentNode?.insertBefore(detailElement, rowElement.nextSibling);
      
    } else {
      
      // Toggle visibility or update content
      detailElement.style.display = detailElement.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
    
  };
```

And my DataGrid

```
<DataGrid 
....
onRowClick={(params) => toggleRowExpansion(params.id)}
```

This works fine and is showing the div under the row and it can be collapsed:

[image]

The problem is that I want to use a Custom Component that will have some actions.

What I read is that you can convert a component to string using: `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` but going this path if the component has any action or reactivity then I lose all that and makes sense.

How can I achieve this?